# X509Certificate2 different in widows and linux in .NET Core Application

Tags: linux, windows, ssl, x509certificate2, xml-signature

I have a console application written in .NET Core 2.1, and has two functionalities -
one: load a certificate chain (certificate, intermediate certificate and root certificate), as well as a private key, that are located in one .p12 file created from .p7b file and .key file. This is loaded  in one `X509Certificate2` class, using the `ctor(string filename, string password)`

The setup that I have works fine on Windows, but when I deploy the app in Linux environment (debian 9), and when I try to sign the message, I get an error: `A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.`
here is the code for loading the certificate:

```
public CertificateManager(IOptions<CertificateSettings> options)
{
   var settings = options.Value;
   _filePath = settings.Path;
   _password = settings.Password;
   Certificate = new X509Certificate2(_filePath, _password);
}
```

The code for the xml signing is as:

```
public string SignMessage(XmlNode message)
    {
        
        var signed = new SignedXml((XmlElement)message)
        {
            SigningKey = _certificateManager.Certificate.PrivateKey,
        };
        var referenceID = message.Attributes[PAResDescr.PAResID].Value;

        signed.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA1Url;

        var reference = new Reference { Uri = $"#{referenceID}" };
        reference.DigestMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigSHA1Url;
        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
        signed.AddReference(reference);


        var keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        var keyInfoData = new KeyInfoX509Data(_certificateManager.Certificate, X509IncludeOption.WholeChain);
        keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoData);


        signed.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

        signed.ComputeSignature();

        return signed.GetXml().OuterXml;
    }
```

As I mentioned, this code works fine when I run it on Windows machine, but when I run this on Linux (Debian 9) I get an the mentioned error, here is the whole stacktrace:

```
at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.KeyInfoX509Data..ctor(X509Certificate cert, X509IncludeOption includeOption)
at Payment.Service.Cryptography.LocalCertificateSigner.SignMessage(XmlNode message) in /home/juls/Projects/ACS/Payment.Service/Cryptography/LocalCertificateSigner.cs:line 44
```

The interesting part is, that when I run this without the `X509IncludeOption.WholeChain` constructor parameter, the error is gone, but in  the signature is included only the signing certificate, not the whole chain. My thoughts are, that when the certificate is loaded, in windows it loads the whole chain, but in linux it loads only the signing certificate. I couldn't find anything related here or in the rest of the internet, so I'm asking if anyone have any clue, what is my problem here?

Regards,
Julian

Comment: `X509Certificate2` objects are the same in .NET Core regardless of the platform you are running on. The problem is that your Linux box is either do not trust the root certificate of the current certificate or cannot build the chain up to a trusted root CA. .NET Core uses different chaining engines on different platforms.

Comment: The problem was that the intermediate and root certificates were not trusted by the Linux machine. As @Crypt32 suggested, adding them to the trusted store, soled the problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the intermediate and root certificates were not trusted by the Linux machine. As @Crypt32 suggested in the first comment below the question, adding them to the trusted store, solved the problem. Thanks !